# Python: adding a delay after each item when dumping results from a list of URLs into a JSON file

Tags: python, json, api, url, time

I've got the following script which puts the results of a list of several API calls into a list and then writes that list to a JSON file, but I'm restricted to 2 calls per second.

```
with open('data.json', 'a') as fp:
    json.dump([requests.get(url).json() for url in urls], fp, indent=2)
```

Is it possible to achieve this with `time.sleep(0.5)`? If so, I'm not quite sure how to as this stage.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first collect the data, then in the end JSON-encode it and write it down:

```
import json
import requests
import time

results = []  # a list to hold the results
for url in urls:  # iterate over your URLs sequence
    results.append(requests.get(url).json())  # fetch and append to the results
    time.sleep(0.5)  # sleep for at least half a second
with open("data.json", "a") as f:  # not sure if you want to append, tho
    json.dump(results, f, indent=2)  # write everything down as JSON
```

Effectively, you're doing the same, anyway, you just needed to unravel the list comprehension part so that you can inject `time.sleep()` to it.

Comment: Superb! Thanks @zwer